# Combine dataframes of different sizes without NAN's

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have 2 dataframes that I would like to combine the following way:
df1:

```
I   A           B           C
0   0.719391    0.091693    one
1   0.951499    0.83716     one
2   0.975212    0.224855    one
3   0.80762     0.031284    three
4   0.63319     0.342889    one
5   0.075102    0.899291    two
6   0.502843    0.773424    two
7   0.032285    0.242476    one
8   0.794938    0.607745    one
```

df2:

```
I   Y   C
0   1   one
1   2   two
2   3   three
```

The result be:
df_comb:

```
I   A           B           C       Y
0   0.719391    0.091693    one     1
1   0.951499    0.83716     one     1
2   0.975212    0.224855    one     1
3   0.80762     0.031284    three   3
4   0.63319     0.342889    one     1
5   0.075102    0.899291    two     2
6   0.502843    0.773424    two     2
7   0.032285    0.242476    one     1
8   0.794938    0.607745    one     1
```

So every row in column Y of df_comb where the value of columns C is matched to a value in column C of df2 should have the corresponding value of column Y in df2 in it's column Y.

I tried some join and merge without success.
Does anyone knows how to do this without using a for loop?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your unsuccessful attempt at merge? Because this definitely looks like a merge problem.

Comment: @ayhan Can you find a dupe?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ jezrael beat me to it. :)

Comment: @ayhan pleasantly surprising!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`df.map`

```
df['Y']=df.C.map(df2.set_index('C')['Y'])
df
Out[164]: 
   I         A         B      C  Y
0  0  0.719391  0.091693    one  1
1  1  0.951499  0.837160    one  1
2  2  0.975212  0.224855    one  1
3  3  0.807620  0.031284  three  3
4  4  0.633190  0.342889    one  1
5  5  0.075102  0.899291    two  2
6  6  0.502843  0.773424    two  2
7  7  0.032285  0.242476    one  1
8  8  0.794938  0.607745    one  1
```

---

**Option 2**
`df.merge`

```
df.merge(df2, on='C', how='left')

          A         B      C  Y
0  0.719391  0.091693    one  1
1  0.951499  0.837160    one  1
2  0.975212  0.224855    one  1
3  0.633190  0.342889    one  1
4  0.032285  0.242476    one  1
5  0.794938  0.607745    one  1
6  0.807620  0.031284  three  3
7  0.075102  0.899291    two  2
8  0.502843  0.773424    two  2
```

---

**Option 3**
`df.replace`

```
df.C.replace(df2.set_index('C').Y)

I
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    1
8    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Merged our answers, hope that's okay.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nice replace here:-)

Comment: Guys, it's a very nice answer(s) +1 :)

Comment: Hmmm, if dupe answer the best is remove it? Or not? What do you think, guys?

Comment: or `community wiki` ?

Comment: @jezrael since this contain more option than the one you marked as dup , I do not think remove it is the best option here, make it community :-)

Comment: @Wen - also join should be added ;)

Comment: @jezrael let us do it :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for the silly question: I'm still learning python